# Node cannot find modules already installed

Tags: javascript, node.js

Been trying to do some testing with Javascript, however out of nowhere I've started to get the following error when I run my tests:

```
NAME@NAME dir2 % npx hardhat test
An unexpected error occurred:

Error: Cannot find module 'node:console'
Require stack:
- /Users/NAME/Documents/dir1/dir2/test/Simulation:I-hardhat.js
- /Users/NAME/Documents/dir1/dir2/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js
...
..
.
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
```

I don't know what caused this error, as it started to show up out of nowhere. Things I have tried:

- install console using `npm install console --save`
- Uninstall && Install Node from homebrew.
- Uninstall && Install Node from the website.
- Remove the node_modules file and install it again.

This might be of help:

```
NAME@NAME % node -v
v14.16.1
NAME@NAME % npm -v
6.14.12

NAME@NAME % which node
/usr/local/bin/node
NAME@NAME % whereis node
NAME@NAME % which npm
/usr/local/bin/npm
NAME@NAME % whereis npm
```

Your time is much appreciated,

mac os Big Sur 11.2.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using this to call the module?

`const console = require('console');`

Comment: Thank you! I completely missed it until you pointed it out.

Answer (score 0):

I think, if  you want to use a module from any directory, you need to install it globally with `npm install -g`. And if you will be have problem `code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'`, you can fix this issue by running `npm install --save form-data`.